# set service class from .env or ENV in system

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4

I have symfony 4 setup

in `services.yml` I have the following configured service

```
MyCompany\Interfaces\QueueProducerInterface:
  class: MyCompany\Service\KafkaProducer
  arguments:
     $queueConfig: '@queue_config'
```

I want to change the setting dynamically in my `.env`file, so I can inject it later, depending on the env (dev, production)....so I tried something like this:

in `.env`

```
QUEUE_DRIVER="MyCompany\Service\KafkaProducer"
```

and now in `services.yaml`

```
    MyCompany\Interfaces\QueueProducerInterface:
#      class: MyCompany\Service\KafkaProducer
      class: '.%env(QUEUE_DRIVER)%'
      arguments:
         $queueConfig: '@queue_config'
```

but when I run for instance `composer update` I get a container error

```
Script cache:clear returned with error code 1
!!
!!  In Compiler.php line 112:
!!
!!    Incompatible use of dynamic environment variables "QUEUE_DRIVER" found in p
!!    arameters.
!!
!!
!!  In AbstractRecursivePass.php line 123:
!!
!!    Invalid service "MyCompany\Interfaces\QueueProducerInterface": class ".%env(
!!    QUEUE_DRIVER)%" does not exist.
!!
!!
```

how do I solve this problem? or better said, how can I set the value of this class dynamically depending on ENV.

Comment: It seems that you cannot use env var into the service class name because env vars are not available at compile time. see https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/20850

Comment: Maybe the error message should be more explicit. Instead of "Incompatible use of dynamic environment variables" say "Cannot use an env var at compile time because they are not available. For class names use hardcoded strings." ;)

Answer (score 1):

I solved it, by creating a `services.yaml` inside the folder `config/packages/dev/` and also `config/packages/prod/' with different settings.

Answer (score 0):

In newer versions of symfony you can do that in a single `services.yaml` using the `when@xxx` syntax and use an interface, like this:

For example:

```
parameters:
    my.nice.service.class: Some\NameSpace\RealServiceClass

when@dev:
    parameters:
        my.nice.service.class: Some\DevelHelper\RealServiceClass

Some\NameSpace\WorkerInterface:
    class: '%my.nice.service.class%'
```

In your consuming class just typehint the `Some\NameSpace\WorkerInterface` interface in the constructor and it will be injected properly.

Of course the interface `Some\NameSpace\WorkerInterface` must exist in the code and both `RealServiceClass` and `RealServiceClass` must implement the interface.